# python flask - api call doesn't work in deployed app

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application and am trying to troubleshoot why one of my routes doesn't work. I don't think the problem is with the route. The error comes when calling a function which involves an API request.

Here is the route:

```
@app.route("/weather_forecast/<climbing_area>/<city_id>/<lat>/<lon>/<weather_site>")
def weather_forecast(climbing_area, city_id, lat, lon, weather_site):

    sites = db.create_site_list_sqlite()
    daily_forecast = wf.format_daily_forecast(city_id)
    extended_forecast = wf.format_extended_forecast(city_id)
    historical_forecast = wf.get_historical_weather(lat, lon)
    dates = wf.get_date_range()


    return render_template('weather_forecast.html', 
                   climbing_area=climbing_area, 
                   city_id=city_id, 
                   daily_forecast=daily_forecast, 
                   extended_forecast=extended_forecast, 
                   historical_forecast=historical_forecast,
                   dates=dates,
                   lat=lat,
                   lon=lon,
                   weather_site=weather_site,
                   sites=sites,
                   wf=wf)
```

My error comes with the line `daily_forecast = wf.format_daily_forecast(city_id)`

This line uses an API key to request weather data from https://openweathermap.org/api based on the location specified by the city_id argument.

Here is the full error message from the error log:

```
[2020-08-04 12:28:17,529] ERROR in app: Exception on /weather_forecast/American Fork/5779334/40.42/-111.97/Orem [GET]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
 File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
 File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
 File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
 File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
 File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/weather_app_main.py", line 46, in weather_forecast
daily_forecast = wf.format_daily_forecast(city_id)
 File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/weather_forecast.py", line 49, in format_daily_forecast
todays_data = extended_forecast_data[0]['list']
 KeyError: 'list'
```

Again, the `daily_forecast` function which uses an API key to get weather data is referenced in the error log:

```
 File "/home/epurpur/ClimbingWeatherAppFlask/weather_app_main.py", line 46, in weather_forecast
daily_forecast = wf.format_daily_forecast(city_id)
```

But I don't know why? When running the app locally, there is no problem here. There must be something else I am over looking?

Though the last message in the error log is this `todays_data = extended_forecast_data[0]['list']`, this list doesn't exist because there is no data returned from an API call, in the above mentioned `daily_forecast` step

Comment: It's a ```KeyError```. You are trying to access **list** in extended_forecast_data object and it does not exists there```todays_data = extended_forecast_data[0]['list']```. Maybe check whether the key exists before getting.

Comment: right, the list doesn't exist because the step before it 'daily_forecast = wf.format_daily_forecast(city_id)' isn't working, which calls for data.  But no data is returned so there is an empty list

Comment: Your question should show the code from the `wf` module (weather_forecast.py) where `todays_data` is assigned.  You've only shown the code which calls this, instead of the code where the exception is generated.